# How to catch a Paperclip.run(cmd) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am in the process of upgrading an old rails app and am upgrading Paperclip. I have a custom processor that uses Paperclip.run to run some manual convert statements in my processor. Occasionally a bad file slips through that imagemagick doesn't like, so we would catch the error and respond to the user.

The old way was as follows(This code fails):

```
begin
   Paperclip.run("convert", cmd)
rescue PaperclipCommandLineError
     raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the tiles for #{@basename}"   if whiny
end
```

Which used to catch the command error and raise a validation error. This no longer works because there is no longer a PaperclipCommandLineError.

Looking at the code it looks like Paperclip.run() uses https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine to handle it's commands. Looking at the cocaine documentation it looks like we could catch the exit code and recover that way with something like:

```
begin
  Cocaine::CommandLine.new("convert", cmd)
rescue Cocaine::ExitStatusError => e
  #error handling here
end
```

Will Paperclip.run() return a Cocaine::ExitStatusError if there is a problem? Or, since I am just using Paperclip.run() as a wrapper to run my command, should I use Cocaine::CommandLine instead? Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct with Paperclip now using `cocaine` for commands now.  However the call to use `cocaine` is internal so you can still use `Paperclip.run`.

The arguments to `run` are a little different:

```
def run(cmd, arguments = "", interpolation_values = {}, local_options = {})
```

so you might need to work on your `cmd` a little to get it in the correct format.  You can see examples in the source though where it makes calls `file` and the various ImageMagick functions.

You should be able to trap your error with:

```
begin
   Paperclip.run(cmd)
rescue ArgumentError, Cocaine::CommandLineError
   raise Paperclip::Error.new("There was an error processing the tiles for #{@basename}") if @whiny
end
```

Note you also have to raise the Paperclip slightly differently now as `PaperclipError` no longer exists.